# CrossDomain issue when making Ajax call to Web API

Tags: ajax, rest, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api

I have several projects in my solution: WebApi and WebPage project
Web API project returns me some data using the following Url:

```
http://localhost:63983/api/values
```

My main web project it uses another Port:

```
http://localhost:63421/#/
```

And now when I run my Web Project, I'm trying to make a simple Ajax call to my WebApi
And here I get a very strange error: 
Firebug shows status: 200OK, but it marks it with a red color and I get no data.

I presume it has something to do with cross-domains maybe.

Comment: Just in case if somebody needs help, there is a working solution here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-cross-domain-ajax-call-with-get-request/

Answer (score 0):

You guess is exactly right. You are not allowed to read data on a different domain. A domain is both the `domain name` and the `port`. This also applies when one is on `HTTP` (port 80), and the other is on `HTTPS` (port 443)

You can explicitly allow you WebProject to make AJAX calls to your WebApi by setting a header value in the content returned by your WebApi. So when you make an AJAX call to http//localhost:63983/api/values, it should include the HTTP header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:63421
```

More details can be found here: http://css.dzone.com/articles/ajax-requests-other-domains

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CORS support in Web API using the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` nuget package.

After installing the above package, having the following configuration should fix your issue.

`config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));`

More info here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I made a quick research and it seems it's possible to use this package only if I use WebAPI2 and this is not the case